# how to find mutual friend code in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hi this function is supposed to find the mutual friends of a person through two people having mutual friends. I've been stuck on this and need help! thank you

def get_friends_of_friends(person_to_friends: Dict[str, List[str]], \
                           person: str) -> List[str]:

```
"""
>>> get_friends_of_friends({'Izuku Midoriya': ['Jotaru Kujo', 'Joseph Joestar', 'Gyro Zeppeli'], 'Jotaro Kujo': ['Gyro Zeppeli', 'Joseph Joestar']}, 'Izuku Midoriya')

    ['Joseph Joestar', 'Gyro Zeppeli']
"""

friend = []

for key in person_to_friends:
    if key == person:
        person_to_friend.append(key)

return friend
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Comment: code doesnt work and just gives me an empty list when its suppose to give a list of strings of the mutual friends in this case 'Izuku Midoriya' and 'Gyro Zeppeli'

Comment: you're not appending anything to the list that you are returning in the code you showed.

Comment: oh okay how would i fix it if its okay to ask

Comment: You're appending to person_to_friend when it looks like you should be appending to friend, since that is what you are returning.